# fancybox jquery plugin links to image but doesn't overlay

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

On this site that I'm working on for work - http://www.basicliving.com - when you click on the mother's day specials ad it brings you to a seperate page with the image and a grey background. I'm using fancybox and I have followed the directions on the fancybox site perfectly. I've checked in firebug and all the files are there and connected. What it should do is just overlay the image with a grey, but somewhat transparent background so that you can still see the homepage content behind the image. Here's the code...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        /* This is basic - uses default settings */

        $("#init_over").fancybox({
            'speedIn'       :   600, 
            'speedOut'      :   200, 
            'overlayShow'   :   false,
            'hideOnContentClick': true
        });

    });
```

and html...

```
<a id="init_over" href="<?php echo DIR_WS_TEMPLATES . TEMPLATE_NAME; ?>/images/mothersDayAd.jpg">
            <img src="<?php echo DIR_WS_TEMPLATES . TEMPLATE_NAME; ?>/images/momsDayAd.jpg" alt="Mother's Day Bosch Sale!" /></a>
```

I've also linked the CSS in the head, along with the necessary JQuery and fancybox scripts. They are all there. I've checked the site FAQ's and all it said was, "make sure everything is installed properly". I've googled it and read other questions on stack and I couldn't fix so I thought it's time to ask... Thanks!

Comment: I've also tried the selector with the a in front of it so I know that doesn't work either. $("a#init_over").fancybox

Comment: $("#init_over").fancybox is not a function
Looks like the plugin is not initialized.

Comment: yes, I noticed that error too... I can't for the life of me figure out why it is not initialized though, as I said before I have followed the steps to installing the plugin and even taken the code out and re-installed... any ideas what could be causing this error? It's driving me crazy.

Comment: okay it appears that the real source of the problem is that the fancybox function is not defined. In the firebug console it says "$('init_over').fancybox is not a function"...

Comment: You have some html errors on your page. Try to get your html cleaned up first before digging into js issues.

Comment: Easier said than done TJ... This website was built on a template system that incorporated a lot of nested tables... horrible, I know. I am redesigning it and I am trying to convert everything from tables (stupid) to divs and such (better). But there are certain parts of the html code that are way too much trouble to tamper with. Besides, I highly doubt any of those html errors are effecting the js, but thanks for the tip. I'll try and clean up what I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have included jQuery twice.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="templates/OS03C00309/includes/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that, but I've taken it out now (the top script because the bottom one is newer) and it still is not performing the way it should. On a separate note... nice avatar

Comment: you still have two versions of jQuery : v1.7.1 and v1.4.4

Comment: JFK is right. Search for this line: '<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>', It might help, to collect all js-files in the same area (at the end of the body tag, i.e.) to make the code a bit more viewable.

Comment: okay man... I owe you an apology. I thought you were crazy but after 2 days of work I finally found the file that was putting the extra jquery in there. This site was built by someone else and it's just a rat's nest of files and includes and nested tables. Removed extra jquery tag and works great now. Thanks!